# Ruby on Rails 3 simple-navigation could not find in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, dbmigrate

I've be using simple-navigation and it's working fine. I've just tried to do a database migration using:

```
rake db:migrate
```

and get the error:

test me$ rake db:migrate
(in /Users/me/test)
Could not find simple-navigation-3.2.0 in any of the sources
Try running `bundle install`.

I've run bundle install and I have a working navigation in the application. Running the db migration is the only problem I'm having.

Any ideas?

Comment: As a workaround I comment out the line 'gem "simple-navigation"' in my Gemfile, run bundle install, run the migration, uncomment the line, run bundle install again. Surely there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my environment. I installed rvm and installed the latest version of Ruby and everything works fine now.